# Kubernetes: /usr/local/bin/kubectl is version 1.19.0, and is incompatible with Kubernetes 1.16.2

Tags: kubernetes

I am setting up Kubernetes for the first on my local machine using Minikube.

I installed kubectl on my local machine using:

```
curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

However, when I run the command:

```
minikube start
```

I get the following error:

```
  minikube 1.12.3 is available! Download it: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.12.3
  To disable this notice, run: 'minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false'

  minikube v1.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
  Starting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
⌛  Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.2 on Docker '18.09.9' ...
  Relaunching Kubernetes using kubeadm ... 
⌛  Waiting for: apiserver
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
⚠️  /usr/local/bin/kubectl is version 1.19.0, and is incompatible with Kubernetes 1.16.2. You will need to update /usr/local/bin/kubectl or use 'minikube kubectl' to connect with this cluster
```

I don't seem to understand what the error means by:

```
⚠️  /usr/local/bin/kubectl is version 1.19.0, and is incompatible with Kubernetes 1.16.2. You will need to update /usr/local/bin/kubectl or use 'minikube kubectl' to connect with this cluster
```

I can't remember installing **minikube** or **Kubernetes** before now on my local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out what the issue was.

I ran the command `kubectl version` and I got the following output:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", 

GitCommit:"e19964183377d0ec2052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", 

BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:30:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", 

GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", 

BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:09:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

It showed me the date when I installed Kubernetes using **minikube** installer, which was sometime in 2019 when I was trying out **Kubenetes** initially.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

There are 2 solutions:

**Solution 1**

Uninstall older/previous versions of **Kubernetes** using **minikube** on the Linux machine:

```
minikube stop; minikube delete
docker stop (docker ps -aq)
rm -r ~/.kube ~/.minikube
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/localkube /usr/local/bin/minikube
systemctl stop '*kubelet*.mount'
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
docker system prune -af --volumes
```

Or on Mac:

```
minikube stop; minikube delete &&
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) &&
rm -rf ~/.kube ~/.minikube &&
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/localkube /usr/local/bin/minikube &&
launchctl stop '*kubelet*.mount' &&
launchctl stop localkube.service &&
launchctl disable localkube.service &&
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/ &&
docker system prune -af --volumes
```

Reinstall a new copy of **minikube**:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube_latest_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i minikube_latest_amd64.deb
```

And then run the command below to pull a new base image of Kubernetes:

```
minkube start
```

This pulls a new image of **Kubernetes**, and also configures **kubectl** to use **minikube**.

**Solution 2**:

Run the command below to downgrade **kubectl** to the same version as **Kubenetes** on the local machine:

```
minikube kubectl
```

This will install the **kubectl** compatible version for **Kubernetes** using **minikube**

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Installing kubectl again solved my issue.

In my case there was no need to uninstall older version I just followed installation steps again and it worked for me.

Update the apt package index and install packages needed to use the Kubernetes apt repository:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl
```

If you use Debian 9 (stretch) or earlier you would also need to install apt-transport-https:

```
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

Download the Google Cloud public signing key:

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

Add the Kubernetes apt repository:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

Update apt package index with the new repository and install kubectl:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubectl
```

**I Hope this works for you too**